# How To Style Background Color Outside Of Body

Tags: ios, css, mobile, background

If you use my demo below on Safari on iOS and then scroll up and down you will be able to scroll outside the body until you release your finger from the touchscreen. Outside the body the background is white. How do you change the color outside the body element?

I have tried styling the HTML tag, searching Google for answers and I cannot find any luck. I have seen websites out there were when you scroll above the body the color was something else than white.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
            }

            div {
                background: black;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using `WKWebView` or do you just want your HTML to display properly on Safari? If the latter is the case, you might want to take a look here: https://www.bram.us/2016/05/02/prevent-overscroll-bounce-in-ios-mobilesafari-pure-css/.

Answer (score 1):

There's a metadata option called `theme-color`, which sets the colour of the background outside the body and the tab colour on Safari on iOS, as well as on other mobile browsers. Looks like support for this was added to Safari in 2021, [according to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color#browser_compatibility)

To set the background to black, you would add the meta tag inside your `<head>` like this:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="black" />
</head>
```

You can set this based on the preferred colour scheme, too:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="cyan" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="black" />
</head>
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color